# Sun Solaris 10, /opt folder accidentally become file

Tags: solaris, sun

While i was copying some files in /opt folder through WINSC, the /opt folder become file. Can you please inform how to make this again in folder?

Comment: What is WINSC and what commands did you run to do this damage ?

Comment: Do you mean WinSCP?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this isn't what you want but I can't think what your problem is as I've never heard of a directory becoming a file without it being deleted and recreated as a file anyway

```
mv /opt /optsafe
mkdir /opt
```

Comment: How i will return back the files which were in /opt folder, as /opt is now become a file? I was trying to copy the patches in /opt folder through WINSCP ?

Comment: @ImranKhan: after having searched your filesystem just in case it has been moved elesewhere I suspect you'll be reaching for your backups.